# Why base classes must have default new?

Tags: vb.net

I got this error

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/misc/bc30387

And I wonder why.

What about if I never want to call parameterless new in both base and derived classes?

I can do that if I don't use inheritance. Why using inheritance means I can no longer do so?

To repeat the issue

What's the explanation? So NOT every classes need parameterless new but classes with inheritance must? That doesn't make sense.

What about if I never call derived class with parameter less constructor. I don't intent for the class to ever be constructed without parameter.

For example, say, I want to create a class without parameterless constructor. I can do that right.

But say I want to split the class into two. Parent and child class. I want BOTH not to ever have parameterless constructor.

It seems that I can't do that can I? If such is the case, can anyone please confirm it.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: The link you posted gives a perfectly clear explanation.

Comment: The question resolves around the fact that I found it very strange that I cannot create classes with no parameterless constructor if and only if I use inheritance.

Comment: If that is the case, would anyone please confirm that it's so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link says that if you have an explicit constructor in your base class with parameters and no parameterless one than you cannot leave your derived class without constructor. Because VB.NET cannot create an implicit constructor for derived class.

If you don't write any constructors for both, it is perfectly valid.

```
public class Base

End Class

Public Class Derived 
    Inherits Base

End Class
```

However you cannot declare a derived class without an explicit constructor like below. Because VB.NET cannot determine how to initialize base class.

```
public class Base
    Public sub New(ByVal Item As Integer)

    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Derived 
    Inherits Base

End Class
```

To overcome this issue you can declare a default constructor on derived class which calls base class constructor with a default value.

```
public class Base
    Public sub New(ByVal Item As Integer)

    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Derived 
    Inherits Base

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New(5)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Why can vb.net create parameter constructor using parameter constructor of base class? Oh because constructors are special functions that don't simply get inherited?

Comment: All classes must have a constructor to initialize itself. If there is no parameterless constructor, compiler cannot determine which one should be called and cannot pass parameters with its own, appearently. So you need to call it explicitly. For inheritance part, derived classes should not bother with base class internals and it just needs to call only the base ctor to do the init.